# install tensorflow 2.3.1 with conda

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, anaconda

I recently switched my System to Ubuntu (20.04.2 LTS)

I installed Anaconda and I want to work with spyder.
now when I try to install tensorflow==2.3.1 (which I need to work with tensorflow-quantum) I get this message:

~$ conda install tensorflow==2.3.1

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow==2.3.1

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
```

Do I have to add another channel? If so, which one?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, with using the base(root) environment. Unfortunately can I not get it working within my custom environment, no idea why..
I am going to stick with base then.